# What version of tridion cd_cwa and cd_tdf custom jar released to support Tridion web 8.5?

Tags: web8.5

What is the latest custom JAR version for Tridion **cd_wai** and **cd_tdf** are released to support **Tridion Web 8.5** version?

Currently we are using the below version JARs.

- `cd_cwa:2011`
- `cd_tdf:2011`

Answer (score 3):

CWA does not work on 8.5 - as far as I know there is no compatibility release for this application, as it has been superseded by DXA (and some would say DD4T prior to that).

Keep in mind that CWA served many of us very well for **15 years** and is really about time for it to retire.